# Calculate t without data set

Tags: regression, t-test, standard-error

How would you go about calculating test statistic t from a regression equation and the standard error of the slope?

Answer (score 3):

For a given predictor, $$t_{(df)}=\frac {\hat b-b_0}{SE_\hat b}$$ where $\hat b$ is the regression coefficient estimated from a sample, $SE_\hat b$ is its standard error, $b_0$ is the value of the $b$ population parameter assumed by the null hypothesis (zero by default), and $df=n-k$, where $n$ is the number of observations, and $k$ is the number of regression coefficients estimated in the model, including the intercept's.

<sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-statistic#Definition) answered this better than I did at first, so I've reorganized things somewhat to suit it. You may find several other details included there useful, including an exception for certain time series where *t* is not normally distributed.</sup>